# Remove All Keys from Redis in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, redis, predis

I was able to flash all keys from **terminal** using `redis-cli flushdb`. I have been searching for a while, took me an hour in order to find the simple command to do it in **php**.

> I didn't find it on stackoverflow so I wanted to post it to save
>   someone precious time.

Library Used: [Predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis)

Comment: Are you using any redis PHP library (like e.g. [Predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis)?)

Comment: yes I should include that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have the redis connection you can simply do  `$redis->flushDB();` to delete all keys from the selected database.

Or if you are using **laravel** framework you could also do `Redis::flushDB();`

Comment: Laravel also allows you to use `\Cache::store("redis")->flush()`

Comment: yes that one works too. but it deletes the current db keys or all ?

Comment: If the underlying CacheStore is `RedisStore` it just calls flushDB. The advantage is though that if you have code line `\Cache::flush()` then it will keep working when you switch from redis to something else.